# How to get data from datagridview using loop

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am trying to get data from datagridview using for loop i.e take data one by one from row in datagrid and put in listview . but i got an exception 
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index" . 
The data in datagridview is coming from excel sheet .I have following code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
listView1.Visible = true;
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.GridLines = true;
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

//Add column header
listView1.Columns.Add("Recipent Number", 500);
listView1.Columns.Add("Status", 100);

for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    //Add items in the listview
    string[] arr = new string[2];
    ListViewItem itm;

    //Add first item
    arr[0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i+1].Cells["F1"].Value.ToString();
    arr[1] = "Send";
    itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
    listView1.Items.Add(itm);

}
}
```

Comment: When you debug through it, which line throws the error?

Comment: This is C# and not VB.NET. Please remove the VB.NET tag.

Comment: Sorry ! i am removing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error in your for loop condition.

Change it to use "<" rather than "<=" as shown below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    //Add items in the listview
    string[] arr = new string[2];
    ListViewItem itm;

    //Add first item
    arr[0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i+1].Cells["F1"].Value.ToString();
    arr[1] = "Send";
    itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
    listView1.Items.Add(itm);

}
```

Comment: ..and change `dataGridView1.Rows[i+1]` to `dataGridView1.Rows[i]`

Comment: Thanks @Prashant ! You made my night :)

Comment: Thanks @JacobSeleznev :) You made my night too :P